# Angular 6 - Detect when variable change in another part of the app

Tags: angular

I'm using `Ngx-webstorage` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webstorage) annotation to bind properties from local & session storage to typescript variables.

In my app component, the background is defined by one of those properties, called `JuegoDatos` (Set of data). Each JuegoDatos has a file id, that defines the background image of it.

What i want is, when the JuegoDatos change (sessionStorage property, binded to typescript variable) detect it so i can get the new id of the file and update the background.

I made it work by using an interval.

```js
@SessionStorage(GlobalVariable.JUEGO_DATOS_KEY) private juegoDatosActual: JuegoDatos;

    private idImagen: number;
    private urlImagenJuegoDatos: SafeResourceUrl;

// Some code

ngOnInit() {
        setInterval(() => {
            if (this.juegoDatosActual == null || this.juegoDatosActual.imagenFondo == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (this.idImagen === this.juegoDatosActual.imagenFondo.id) {
                return;
            }

            this.idImagen = this.juegoDatosActual.imagenFondo.id;
            this.reloadImagen();
        }, 1000);
    }
```

But it seems a little hacky and very ugly. Also the background flashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the `@SessionStorage` decorator if you want to monitor changes. Inject the `SessionStorageService` and listen for emitted changes.

See the documentation:

https://github.com/PillowPillow/ng2-webstorage#d_sessionStorage

```
   constructor(private storage:SessionStorageService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.storage.observe('boundValue')
        .subscribe((newValue) => {
          console.log(newValue);
        })
    }
```

Comment: I didn't see "The api is identical as the LocalStorageService's" text in Documentation. (Even i was thinking to migrating to LocalStorage). Thanks, works great

Comment: make sure you also unsubscribe the subscription in ngOnDestroy

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `BehaviorSubject` to detect change.

Create a service like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JuegoDatosChangeService {

constructor() { }

public status: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  changeData(value: any) {
    this.status.next(value);
  }
}
```

On change of "JuegoDatos", call the service,

```
this.juegoDatosChangeService.changeData(data);
```

and to detect the change:

```
this.juegoDatosChangeService.status.subscribe((val) => {
    console.log(val)
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the accepted answer serves better this issue in particular, but i'll save your answer to resolve similar without third-party libraries!